# HTML entities are not displayed properly

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, html-entities

I'm building a website with Wordpress, but sometimes (I don't know why) the html entities declared in my php files are displayed as a � (a black diamond with a white question mark). 
 My charset attribute is already set to UTF-8 (as shown in the picure below).
 It could be a problem of the text editor (I'm currently using the built-in editor of Aruba)... How can I make sure that the encoding is right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying your code files into notepad++ and make sure that the encoding is actually set to UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I cannot actually prove it, because i'm pasting the � character, not the original code

Comment: can you add some of your code so I can look at it? Not sure if I can help other then to look at it

Comment: Actually to be sure - UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @fedeTibaldo I'm having the same issue on Wordpress and Aruba, how did you fix it?

Comment: @sdrubish did you try the steps provided in the answer?